# Everytime I try to change the default version of my terminal, VSCode opens up instead

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, windows-terminal

When i am trying to change the default terminal on my windows 11 laptop, the terminal opens up VSCode for some reason. I open the windows terminal, hit settings then VSCode opens up with this settings.json page:

[VSCode settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otz6V.png)

But the thing is I want to have the terminal settings open up, not VSCode. I am trying to change my default terminal from windows terminal to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Windows Terminal are you using? The settings UI for the Terminal was added in 1.7 (IIRC), and I believe the version that originally shipped with Windows 11 was 1.6. Before 1.7, clicking on "settings" would open the `settings.json` file in whatever your default `.json` editor was.

Future readers: If you're hitting this too, make sure to update your Terminal from the Store. Anything >=1.7 should have the Settings UI. At the time of this post, the latest Stable version in the store was 1.12.

Comment: I was able to get this fixed, I needed to update windows terminal in the Microsoft store, thanks though!